# Function to test Tree for presence of Leaves

Tags: haskell

Lets say that we have a type which has this definition :

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Branch [Tree a] deriving (Show,Eq)
```

What I want to make is a function which will return a Boolean.
`False` if my binary tree contains a Leaf and `True` if not.

Here is my code :

```
tester :: Tree a -> Bool
tester (Leaf x) = False
tester (Branch y) = if (Branch (map tester y)) then True else False
```

I know that the main problem of this is that there is no way to evaluate `(Branch (map tester y))` but I really have no idea how to fix it.

I can add a new clause, for example something like this `tester (Branch y) = True`, but I don't think this is a great idea.

Comment: (Note that `if x then True else False` can be simplified to `x`, in all situations.)

Comment: This isn't a binary tree - a binary tree is a tree whose branches are defined `Branch (Tree a) (Tree a)`

Answer (score 5):

`tester` wasn't a descriptive name, so I called it `leafless`, and thinking about `leafy` was much easier.

```
leafy :: Tree a -> Bool
leafy (Leaf x) = True              -- yup - there's a leafy
leafy (Branch ts) = any leafy ts   -- yes if there are any leaves (recursive)
```

We just need to negate the result to get what we wanted.

```
leafless :: Tree a -> Bool
leafless = not.leafy
```

(`any :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool` and `any f xs` checks whether any of the elements of the list satisfy the test (predicate) `f`. It works like `or (map f xs)`.)

You can't `(Branch (map tester y))` because the constructor `Branch` has type `[Tree a] -> Tree a` but `map tester y` is of type `[Bool]`, not `[Tree a]`. You didn't need to write `Branch` on the right hand side; you've used it correctly on the left hand side to pattern-match against branches - it's not needed any more.

Answer (score 4):

There is a more idiomatic way to write `leafless` than writing recursion yourself:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-}
import qualified Data.Foldable as F

data Tree a = Leaf a | Branch [Tree a] deriving (Show,Eq,F.Foldable)

leafless :: Tree a -> Bool
leafless = F.foldl (\x y -> False) True
```

Or even shorter:

```
leafless :: Tree a -> Bool
leafless = null . F.toList
```

Also, your type of tree is called "Rose Tree" and is already in `Data.Tree`

Comment: Note that a branch is defined with a list of nodes, so actually there could be a finite tree whose "tips" were all `Branch []`

Comment: Yeah, fixed :) I actually found that out before reading your comment

Comment: +1 very nice, especially `null.toList` which is absolutely beautiful. It makes me happy to see such things. I admit I felt I ought to use `Foldable` but stuck with a recursive solution, and I'll use the excuse that the questioner sounds inexperienced, so I'm allowed to be basic!